# Under what condition does a Python subprocess get a SIGPIPE?

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I am reading the the Python documentation on the Popen class in the subprocess module section and I came across the following code:

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) also states that

> "The p1.stdout.close() call after starting the p2 is important in order for p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits before p1.

Why must the p1.stdout be closed before we can receive a SIGPIPE and how does p1 knows that p2 exits before p1 if we already closed it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SIGPIPE` is a signal that would be sent if `dmesg` tried to write to a closed pipe. Here, `dmesg` ends up with *two* targets to write to, your Python process and the `grep` process.

That's because `subprocess` clones file handles (using the [`os.dup2()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.dup2)). Configuring `p2` to use `p1.stdout` triggers a `os.dup2()` call that asks the OS to duplicate the pipe filehandle; the duplicate is used to connect `dmesg` to `grep`.

With two open file handles for `dmesg` stdout, `dmesg` is never given a `SIGPIPE` signal if only *one* of them closes early, so `grep` closing would never be detected. `dmesg` would needlessly continue to produce output.

So by closing `p1.stdout` immediately, you ensure that the only remaining filehandle reading from `dmesg` stdout is the `grep` process, and if that process were to exit, `dmesg` receives a `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why is `p1` still writing to stdout though? If python truly calls `dup2(p1.stdout, PIPE)`, then that means that `p1` should not be making any writes to stdout anywhere. When the pipe is closed from p2's end, that will send a proper SIGPIPE. Or does Python not really call dup2, but just creates another file descriptor that it writes to when stdout is written to?

Comment: @darksky: Python calls `dup2(p1.stdout.fileno(), 0) here, so replacing stdin of the child process with the pipe file number. Why does this mean that `p1 should not be making any writes to stdout? `p1.stdout` is **one end of a pipe**, and `p1` is writing to the other end. `p1.stdout` is just the Python process reference to the receiving end of the pipe.

Comment: @darksky: Python calls `dup2(p1.stdout.fileno(), 0)` here, so replacing stdin of the child process with the pipe file number. Why does this mean that `p1 should not be making any writes to stdout? `p1.stdout` is **one end of a pipe**, and `p1` is writing to the other end. `p1.stdout` is just the Python process reference to the receiving end of the pipe.