# Python subprocess.Popen PIPE and SIGPIPE

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pipe, sigpipe

While I browsed posts, I ran into this example below on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6780118/3523935), It is saying `proc1.stdout.close()` is needed to be called for appropriate exit of `proc1`, generating `SIGPIPE`.

```
import subprocess

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'cax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'python'], stdin=proc1.stdout,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

proc1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
out, err = proc2.communicate()
print('out: {0}'.format(out))
print('err: {0}'.format(err))
```

However, I am not clear on that. Please fix my understanding.

1. `SIGPIPE` occurs when a `PIPE` tries to write to closed `PIPE`.
2. Writer `PIPE` is `proc1`'s `stdout` and reader `PIPE` is `proc2`'s `stdin`.
3. `proc1` will exit when `proc2` exit and `proc1` tries to write data to `proc2`'s `stdin PIPE`.
   because

   - `proc2`'s `stdin PIPE` is closed when `proc2` exit
   - `SIGPIPE` happen at `proc1` because `proc1` tries to write to closed `proc2`'s `stdin PIPE`.

From my understanding, `SIGPIPE` would happen and `proc1` would exit, regardless of closing `proc1`'s `stdout`.

What do I miss?

---

### Edit

After reading the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39190346/3523935) from @unutbu's comment......

I think the copied file descriptor(`proc1.stdout`) is writer PIPE, not reader PIPE. thus, there are two writer PIPE and one reader PIPE connected one another.

Therefore, `SIGPIPE` will be generated when `proc2` exit because `proc2` is only one process which has reader PIPE(will be closed when `proc2` exit).

However, the above [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39190346/3523935) seems to say that there are two reader PIPEs by copying `proc1.stdout` so `SIGPIPE` won't be generated even after `proc2` exit because there still is another reader PIPE open. the below is the part of [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39190346/3523935).

> So by closing p1.stdout immediately, you ensure that the only
>   remaining filehandle reading from dmesg stdout is the grep process,
>   and if that process were to exit, dmesg receives a SIGPIPE.

I am not saying that the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39190346/3523935) is wrong but I just want to fix my understanding. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39190250/190597) answer your question?

Comment: another link for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046779/explain-example-from-python-subprocess-module/6046866

Comment: @unutbu, Thank you again, I edit my question after reading the post in your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'cax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

creates this a pipe between the parent process and `proc1`:

```
|        |         |       |
| parent |-<-----<-| proc1 |                   
|        | ^       |       |
           |                     
       p1.stdout
```

`p1.stdout` is what the parent would read to obtain (stdout) output from `proc1`.

```
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'python'], stdin=proc1.stdout,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

connects a copy of the pipe from proc1 to proc2:

```
|        |         |       |         |       |
| parent |-<-----<-| proc1 |->----->-| proc2 | 
|        |         |       |         |       |
```

By calling `p1.stdout.close()`, we close the parent processes's side of the pipe:

```
|        |         |       |         |       |
| parent |       <-| proc1 |->----->-| proc2 | 
|        |         |       |         |       |
```

Now when `proc2` terminates, its side of the pipe is also closed:

```
|        |         |       |         |       |
| parent |       <-| proc1 |->       | proc2 | 
|        |         |       |         |       |
```

The next time `proc1` tries to write to the pipe, a SIGPIPE signal is generated,
which allows `proc1` to terminate since it knows no one is listening on the other end of its pipes.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I get clear. I had seemed to misunderstand on `subprocess.PIPE`.

Comment: It may sound very basic but what is parent process in first command?

Comment: @pankajmishra: The parent process is the process which is running the python script -- the one that calls `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the answer